# How to take an average of a column while only considering the values greater than 300 in R

Tags: r, csv

I have a dataframe containing values. I want to take an average of each column but I want to only take into consideration those values that are greater or equal to 300.

```
Example: Dataframe[,1]
      100
      200
      250
      300
      300
      400
      400

    Average = 350.
```

Comment: If you search in SO, you'll find a lot of example of subsetting.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Conditional summing (R)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4364283/conditional-summing-r)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mean(ifelse(Dataframe[,1] >= 300, Dataframe[,1], NA), na.rm = TRUE)
```

and for all columns at once:

```
do.call("cbind", lapply(DataFrame, function(x){mean(ifelse(x >= 300, x, NA), na.rm = TRUE)}))
```

Comment: Just use standard subsetting `mean(Dataframe[,1][Dataframe[,1] >= 300])` or `lapply(Dataframe, function(x) mean(x[x >= 300]) )`